# Elisp function to open file name with space?

Tags: shell-command, filenames, call-process

To open a file with default associated application, I have this function, which works as I expect, except with a file name that has space:

```lisp
    (defun open-a-file ()
        (interactive)
        (let ((process-connection-type nil))
          (shell-command
           (format "xdg-open %s" (read-file-name "Open: ")))))
```

This definition also doesn't work with a file name that contains a space char:

```lisp
    (defun open-a-file ()
        (interactive)
        (let ((process-connection-type nil))
          (shell-command
           (format "xdg-open %s" (shell-quote-argument (read-file-name "Open: "))))))
```

How can I fix the function?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"? How does it break? FWIW, I create a file `a b` with a space in its name. I then run `(shell-command (format "xdg-open %s" (shell-quote-argument (read-file-name "Open: "))))`, type `a b` at the prompt and it opens the file with no problem. But `call-process` is a better alternative as the answer below points out.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `call-process` instead of `shell-command`:

```
(defun open-a-file ()
  (interactive)
  (call-process "xdg-open" nil 0 nil (read-file-name "Open: ")))
```

One large difference between the two is that `call-process` does not invoke a shell, and thus does not accept shell syntax. It also takes all of the arguments separately; they do not need to be assembled into a valid command line. This eliminates all ambiguity resulting from the spaces in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Try this boss.
Works with input like `file name` or `/path/to/file name` or `path/to/file name`.
Most importantly, even with `~/file name`.

```
(defun open-a-file ()
    (interactive)
    (call-process "xdg-open" nil 0 nil (expand-file-name (read-file-name "Open: "))))
```